# Expresso-Store: New Payment Plugins - Where do we find them?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

What does one do if a payment plugin hasn't been developed yet for Beanstream.
Does Exp-resso add updates to the payment gateways they support?

Comment: Perhaps too late for you, but I just wrote a [Beanstream gateway for Store](https://github.com/amphibian/omnipay-beanstream).

Answer (score 1):

You could either develop your own custom gateway integration or contact Exp:resso to get a quote for building it for you. The payment library in Store, [CI-Merchant](https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant), is open source so you can checkout the existing gateway integrations on github.

Adrian, the developer of Store, says as much in a similar question: [Exp-resso Store Custom Payment Gateway / Sagepay Form](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10278/exp-resso-store-custom-payment-gateway-sagepay-form)

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with a little PHP then it's not too too difficult to create your own payment gateway to integrate with Store. [Beanstream's API seems to be well documented](https://beanstreamsupport.pbworks.com/w/page/26445764/Transaction%20Processing%20API) so you could either give it a go yourself or pass it on to another developer to build.

If you're having a go yourself then the best way to start is by taking a look at the existing payment gateways that come bundled with Store. They provide a good example of what you need to do and then you can edit the codebase to fall in line with the Beanstream documentation.

If a payment gateway proves popular enough then it may well be included in a future release of Store but that would go down to demand.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct - we don't generally add new gateways unless they are sponsored.

Our payment library is [open source](https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant), so if you have PHP development experience it's possible to develop the gateway yourself.

Alternatively, email support@exp-resso.com if you are interested in a quote for custom development.

Comment: Quote received, now I need to see if my EE programmer can squeeze it in.